QGStreamer + Widget
Всем привет. пишу приложение на с++ qt использую библиотеку QGStreamer
https://github.com/GStreamer/qt-gstreamer.git (взял приложение voip)
имеется следующий код
#include "ui_voip.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QDialog>

#include <QGlib/Connect>
#include <QGlib/Error>
#include <QGst/Init>

#include <QGst/Pipeline>
#include <QGst/ElementFactory>
#include <QGst/Pad>
#include <QGst/Structure>
#include <QGst/Bus>
#include <QGst/Message>

class VideoCall : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit VideoCall(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~VideoCall();

private Q_SLOTS:
    void on_startCallButton_clicked();
    void on_endCallButton_clicked();

    //keep the rtcp ports in sync with the rtp ports on the UI
    void on_audioRtpSrcSpinBox_valueChanged(int value) { m_ui.audioRtcpSrcSpinBox->setValue(value + 1); }
    void on_audioRtpDestSpinBox_valueChanged(int value) { m_ui.audioRtcpDestSpinBox->setValue(value + 1); }
    void on_videoRtpSrcSpinBox_valueChanged(int value) { m_ui.videoRtcpSrcSpinBox->setValue(value + 1); }
    void on_videoRtpDestSpinBox_valueChanged(int value) { m_ui.videoRtcpDestSpinBox->setValue(value + 1); }

    void on_endCallButton_2_clicked();

private:
    void onRtpBinPadAdded_1(const QGst::PadPtr & pad);
    void onRtpBinPadAdded_2(const QGst::PadPtr & pad);
    void onBusErrorMessage(const QGst::MessagePtr & msg);

private:
    Ui::VoipExample m_ui;
    QGst::PipelinePtr m_pipeline4Send;
    QGst::PipelinePtr m_pipeline4View_1;
    QGst::PipelinePtr m_pipeline4View_2;
};

VideoCall::VideoCall(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    m_ui.setupUi(this);
//    m_ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);

    on_startCallButton_clicked();
}

VideoCall::~VideoCall()
{
    //cleanup if the pipeline is still active
    if (m_pipeline4Send) {
        on_endCallButton_clicked();
    }
}

void VideoCall::on_startCallButton_clicked()
{
    m_pipeline4View_1 = QGst::Pipeline::create();

    QGst::ElementPtr rtpbin_view_1 = QGst::ElementFactory::make("rtpbin");
    if (!rtpbin_view_1) {
        qFatal("Failed to create rtpbin");
    }
    m_pipeline4View_1->add(rtpbin_view_1);

    QString _video_pipeline4View_1 =
            "udpsrc port=5110 "
            "! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 "
            "! rtph264depay "
            "! avdec_h264 "
            "! videoconvert "
            "! autovideosink";

//        qDebug() << "_audio_pipeline4View: " << _audio_pipeline4View;
    qDebug() << "_video_pipeline4View: " << _video_pipeline4View_1;

    //video content
    QGst::ElementPtr videosrc_1 = QGst::Bin::fromDescription( _video_pipeline4View_1 );

    m_pipeline4View_1->add(videosrc_1);
    videosrc_1->link(rtpbin_view_1, "recv_rtp_sink_2");

    //watch the bus
    m_pipeline4View_1->bus()->addSignalWatch();
    QGlib::connect(m_pipeline4View_1->bus(), "message::error", this, &VideoCall::onBusErrorMessage);

    m_pipeline4View_2 = QGst::Pipeline::create();

    QGst::ElementPtr rtpbin_view = QGst::ElementFactory::make("rtpbin");
    if (!rtpbin_view) {
        qFatal("Failed to create rtpbin");
    }
    m_pipeline4View_2->add(rtpbin_view);

    QString _video_pipeline4View =
            "udpsrc port=5111 "
            "! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264 "
            "! rtph264depay "
            "! avdec_h264 "
            "! videoconvert "
            "! autovideosink";

//        qDebug() << "_audio_pipeline4View: " << _audio_pipeline4View;
    qDebug() << "_video_pipeline4View: " << _video_pipeline4View;

    //video content
    QGst::ElementPtr videosrc = QGst::Bin::fromDescription( _video_pipeline4View );

    m_pipeline4View_2->add(videosrc);
    videosrc->link(rtpbin_view, "recv_rtp_sink_2");


    //watch the bus
    m_pipeline4View_2->bus()->addSignalWatch();
    QGlib::connect(m_pipeline4View_2->bus(), "message::error", this, &VideoCall::onBusErrorMessage);

    m_ui.stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);

    m_ui.videoWidget    ->watchPipeline(m_pipeline4View_1);
    m_ui.videoWidget_2  ->watchPipeline(m_pipeline4View_2);

}
   
void VideoCall::onBusErrorMessage(const QGst::MessagePtr & msg)
{
    qCritical() << "Error from bus:" << msg.staticCast<QGst::ErrorMessage>()->error();
    on_endCallButton_clicked(); //stop the call
}

void VideoCall::on_endCallButton_clicked()
{
    m_pipeline4View_2->setState(QGst::StatePlaying);
}

void VideoCall::on_endCallButton_2_clicked()
{
    m_pipeline4View_1->setState(QGst::StatePlaying);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGst::init(&argc, &argv);

    VideoCall gui;
    gui.show();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"

и все вроде бы нормально. Есть два Pipeline принимают видео поток с разных портов и выводят их в свои виджеты. Вопросов нет, все так, но:

Linux mint(хостовая система на железе) - все работает как надо
На этом же компьютере имеется две виртальные машины (Astra Linux) на них первый  Pipeline запускается в приложении, а второй в отдельном окне и хоть ты тресни
на другом компьютере(хостовая Windows, его не используем) так же имеется виртальная машина Astra Linux, на нем тоже все запускается как положено, в приложении.

Вопрос? Почему не запускается п.2

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
